# How to keep the selenium session alive in heroku?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I have deployed python app in heroku. The app is mainly working with selenium. Whenever i open the app it started new selenium session. I want to make happen in the same selenium session how is it possible?
here is my chrome_options.

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
options.add_argument("--example-flag")
```

Procfile

`web gunicorn app:app`

Comment: Can you show the `Prcofile`?

Comment: @Darkknight added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is the problem I think you haven't defined the workers. So By default `Gunicorn` start three workers which means three selenium session in your case so limit the workers to one and set the time out

`web gunicorn app:app --workers=1 --timeout=50`

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you terminate your session

```
# close the browser window which is currently in focus.
webdriver.close()

# close the browser and terminates the session
webdriver.quit()
```

In the first case (`close()` method) each execution opens a new tab while the Webdriver session is still active